# Python - while loop three conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to make a while loop with multiple conditions:

```
condition = -1
condition1 = 3
x = 2
condition2 = 5
y = 4
while not condition == 1 and not condition1 > x and not condition2 > y:
         print "hey"

condition = 1
condition1 = 3
x = 2
while not condition == 1 and not condition1 > x:
         print "hey"
```

If I put only two conditions, the code prints "hey" but if I put three conditions (that is verified, because i print the condition before to test if it's true), not prints.

I search other questions on the stackoverflow but nothing solves my problem.

Any idea? Please.

Comment: One suggestion...  Instead `not condition1 > x`, you can rewrite much cleaner and more legibly as `condition <= x`

Comment: Check the order of the boolean operator precedence

Comment: As you currently have your code written above, neither while loop will execute.  `while not -1 == 1 and not 3 > 2 and not 5 > 4` and `while not 1 == 1 and not 3 >2`.  It should be obvious why neither while loop executes (3 is indeed greater than 2, 1 actually does equal 1).

Comment: Just above the `while` add `print not condition2 > y`. Its False because condition2 is greater than y.

Comment: also given that body of the while does not change the conditions it's probably better to change while to if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be a lot more readable if you restructured it slightly. Using [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we have that `not A and not B and not C` is the same as `not (A or B or C)`. And since `A or B or C` is the same as `any([A,B,C])` we can just take your first `while` and rewrite it as

```
while not any([ condition == 1, 
                condition1 > x, 
                condition2 > y ]):
   print("Hey")
```

We can see immediately why the loop isn't running because one of those is `True`. Namely `condition1` (which is 3) is greater than `x` (which is 2).

Similarly if we consider the second `while` loop rewritten as

```
while not any([ condition == 1,
                condition1 > x ]):
   print("Hey")
```

Since `condition` equals 1, it fails on the first predicate. And even if `condition` didn't equal 1, `condition1` (which is 3) is greater than `x` (which is 2). So the second predicate also fails.

Answer (score 1):

`condition2` is 5 and `y` is 4.

So `condition2 > y` is true.

So `not condition2 > y` is false.

So `not condition == 1 and not condition1 > x and not condition2 > y` is false.

So the while loop does not run.

By the way, there are two other issues in your code:

1. a semicolon is missing from the first line of the while loop
2. if the while loop runs once, it will never stop. You may want to use a `if` instead to execute the block only once.

Comment: Where do you see a missing semicolon?

Comment: Sorry, I meant colon. And OP edited the code afterward.

Answer (score 0):

`condition=1` and in the program you are specifying `not condition==1` which will return `false` and thus the `while` will evaluate to false. And that is why no output comes.
Similarly all others evaluate to false because of that `not` you placed before each check, and the whole statement is in a whole `false`.